# What is the use of having multiple tags for compilation?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am not an expert in SE politics. I do find it quaint that we have three tags for what appears at first glance as the same exact thing? What's the point in that?

The tags I'm talking about are:

- compile
- compiling
- compilation

Answer (score 3):

There's no good reason. Since anybody above a certain reputation threshold can create tags, however, redundant tags are typical. You can propose tag synonyms once you reach a certain reputation threshold, and until then you can propose them here on meta.

I'll go ahead and merge all of those now (to [compilation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compilation)), but I think it's worth revisiting the topic of blacklisting the tag itself, since I am highly suspicious that the tag represents nothing but off-topic questions.

Comment: Well, there might be a couple of tolerable questions about compiling game development specific Engines / Frameworks etc. I will go over the questions and see.

Comment: I don't think documenting how to compile every game engine under the sun fits into this site's purview, though.